# How to add content along with pictures in drupal?

Tags: drupal

How to add content along with pictures in drupal?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. First, Download and install the [Image](http://drupal.org/project/image) and [ImageField](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield) modules.

With the Image module, you can simply create a new Image node and enter your content.

Alternatively, you can modify a content type. Edit the content type of your choice and click Manage Fields. Add a new Image field. Select File for data type and Image as the data element. Save the content type and head on over to permissions to see if the appropriate user roles can add or edit images. Then create a new node of that content type and you can see the image field available for uploading images.